# how to use dropzne within form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I using Laravel5.2 framework.I want use dropzone within form. obviously, dropzone having own form but i want to use in our top form. when i put dropzone form outside the top form it works fine but when i put inside form then its not working can anyone help me.
here is my code:-

```
enter code here
<form id="CourseAdd" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ 
url('/courses?listid='.base64_encode(convert_uuencode($listid)))}}">{{ 
 csrf_field() }}
    <div>
    <label>Course name</label>
    <input type="text" name="coursename">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Fees</label>
    <input type="text" name="fees">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-z-c">
        <label>Upload Images</label>
        <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="{{ url('/add-images')}}" class="dropzone dropzone-custom">{{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Durayion</label>
    <input type="text" name="duration">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-save">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit </button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

I want to show the dropzone after fees and i want when user upload image it will successfully upload to particular folder

Here is my dropzone code:-

```
enter code here
var maxImageWidth = 300, maxImageHeight = 300;
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        maxFiles: 10,
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 1,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
        clickable: true,
        init: function(){
            var myDropZone = this;
            myDropZone.on('maxfilesexceeded', function(file) {
              myDropZone.removeFile(file);
            });
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                $('.success').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
                file.previewTemplate.setAttribute('id',responseText[0].id);
            });
            this.on("thumbnail", function(file,done) {
                if (file.width < 350 || file.height < 200) {
                    file.rejectDimensions = function() { done("Image width or height should be greater than 350*200"); };
                }
                else {
                    file.acceptDimensions = done;
                }
            });
        },  
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drop your images"
    }
```

Comment: try to replace your dropzone form with div.
replace this : `<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="{{ url('/add-images')}}" class="dropzone dropzone-custom">{{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>`
with : `<div class="dropzone dropzone-custom"> {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>`

Comment: then how do i upload image